# Can cassandra work a non-hadoop environment

Tags: hadoop, cassandra

I am new to cassandra, and considering it for my next bigdata project.

I have a question. Can I host it in a non-hadoop environment? If so, how many nodes I can connect?

Comment: Yes.It doesnt have a dependency on hadoop as it uses its own file system called CFS. Datastax has integrated the apache cassandra with hadoop for features and functionalities

Comment: Thanks Nidhin, Does Cassadra have any definite advantage when it work over HDFS (of Hadoop). Without HDFS it is possible to maintain the large cassandra cluster, with some nodes in Asia and Some nodes in US?

Answer (score 3):

1. Yes, you can. Cassandra has no dependencies other than the most
   basic ones, such as Java. You can read installation guide on
   [official site](http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/install/installTOC.html).
2. Your cluster can have as many nodes as you want. There is no
   described limit on the number of nodes. I read in [this article](http://opensourceconnections.com/blog/2014/09/17/cassandra-summit-2014/) that
   there are clusters which contain more than 1000 Cassandra nodes.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. It helps! But do we have any requirements such as all the nodes has to be in one single network or something? If I maintain a cassandra with 1000 nodes in variuos data centers, will the performance be affected?

Also if Cassandra is in Hadoop, does it have any special advantages?

Comment: Cassandra is designed to work well across many datacenters. You'll be able to determine how many copies of each piece of data are kept per-datacenter, and then tell your application how many datacenters should hold the data before cassandra acknowledges the writes/reads. The consistency and behavior is entirely configurable, so you can tune it to match your application requirements.

Comment: Thanks Jeff, I guess this is doable without HDFS(Hadoop). I would like to know if there is any special advantage if it works on top of HDFS anyway.  I request you to kindly let me know.